# How to expand ms-explorer to automatically handle "connected files" / sidecar files / xmp belonging to jpg?

Tags: c#, windows, plugins, file-management, file-manager

If you locally save a HTML page using Firefox or MS Internet Explorer you will get a HTML file and a sidecar folder containing images that belongs to the page.

If you move the HTML file using Windows Explorer the related sidecar folder is moved, too.

I want to implement a similar behavior for [xmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) - [sidecar files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidecar_file) that belongs to Jpeg images and contains information about the picture similar to `exif`.

Example:
Using Windows Explorer, if I move `test.html` to a different directory the sidecar folder `test-dateien` is moved, too (on a German Windows 7)

I want to implement similar: if I move `test.jpg` I also want to move `test.xmp`.

Does anybody know how this can be done?
Is there already a solution for this?
Can this be done with a kind of plug-in?
Do I have to implement a service?
Can this be done in C#/.Net?

[Update: added the Microsoft term "connected files" to title]

Comment: Until I read your question, I didn't know it did this (I usually save MHT's) but now I really would like to know how it's done too! I can't see anything obvious in the shell functions. Keeping an eye on this one now :-)

Comment: From [reading this](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/jsi-tip-3841-what-windows-2000-connected-file-feature) it seems you just have to create a subfolder with the same name as the file but with "_files" (or language equivalent) appended (but this is HTML only). [MSDN link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887(VS.85).aspx#connected)

Comment: Unfortunately the xmp-sidecarefile-standard does not follow microsofts implementation. I am using exiftools and JPhotoTagger that depend on xmp and its filenamingconvention. Tanks a lot for the links and the new vocabulary "Connected Files" that may be usefull for further research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issued a bounty that attracted many readers but there is no answer how to implement it. :-(

So i assume that this is not possible.